# Formatting of code not possible

Tags: support, code-formatting

I´m not able to format the block with some C# code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201120/confusion-about-wcf-channels) as code.

Is it cause there is a BulletList before the code block?

Comment: Add four more spaces. Total 8 spaces. I just edited the question.

Comment: @hims056 okay, that was easy. I used the buttons of the editor and it seems not to work.

Comment: Yeh we have to add additional four spaces manually in bullets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when formatting code inside of a list, appen 4 *more* spaces (8 in total) to the code block. Example:

```
Normal Code Block
```

- Normal List item

  Paragraph in list item

  ```
  Code in List item
  ```

This was written:

```
    Normal Code Block

  - Normal List item

    Paragraph in list item

        Code in List item
```

For more information, see the **[Formatting Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists)**